# SQL Server: if 2 columns have a specific value then return a third column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL query that does the following.

```
If (field-A = Value1) and (field-B = value1)
then (field-c)
```

So if 2 columns have a certain value I want to return the value of a third column.

Comment: You should be more specific as to what you want in case the two fields do *not* match the required values, because various scenarios are possible. For instance, you could return some default value (like `NULL`), or you could entirely discard the row.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
case 
  when field-A = @value1 and field-B = @value1 then field-C 
  else 'whatever else you want' end
```

Answer (score 2):

`select fieldc from table where fielda='value1' and fieldb='value2'`